# How to implement voice encryption over gsm?

Tags: audio, cryptography, gsm, modem

I am trying to create an encrypted voice-over-GSM communication system.

As we can't use Android, I think it's better to use a RaspberryPI-like solution. (e.g. RaspberryPI + battery + usb modem)

So, the general plan is:

1. record voice
2. encode it with some sort of codec, that allows better compression, than GSM
3. encrypt w/AES
4. modulate it back to sound
5. send modulated sound trought the GSM

So, the general question is: Is there encoding & modulation algorithms, that able to transmit encoded/encrypted voice over GSM?

Or is there a better way to do this **using only GSM, not VoIP**.

Comment: Stream encryption encrypts any kind of stream of bits. So usually the modulation and encryption are in separate layers. The "only" thing to worry about (at that point) is that the time and speed of communication are pretty big hints of what's going down the line. Protecting against those kind of side channels can be very tricky.

Comment: I mean, that there can be a bandwith problem of this sort: "Voice codec XXX giving 456 kb/s data, but YYY, the data modulating/demodulating algorithm can transfer only 123 kb/s trought GSM line".

Comment: Yes so you have to clip some frequencies or compress your data further. Going into this is too broad for this site, which focusses on the development part, which comes after design.